# Geb test: cannot select value of dropdown based on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, geb

I've ran into a problem in my Geb tests where I'm trying to hit a select dropdown box where the first option is null (user wanted it to display blank as the first option).   It is a state field as follows.  Note that the original html has an empty array for the from value.  The state gets filled based on the selection of "USA" as country based on an Ajax call, I've had to edit it a bit.

How do I set my selector to hit the second or third value?   Can I pass values into the selector as an array or something similar?  "100225" the value for USA in both the Firebug HTML and my testing db xml, and "102722" is the state value for "Alabama"

***What I'm trying to achieve is this:  I want to be able to hit one of the unique state values such as 102722 but Geb only hits the very first value which is always null in the select box, although the '102722' value exists both in the Firebug HTML and in my test xml db so I know its there.  As you can see, I've written the Geb selector for State several different ways.  This is the error that always comes back:

|  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: couldn't select option with text or value: 102722

NOTE: Also note below that a println of the value in Geb always returns a null value.

Original form item:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <label id="Country-label" class="toplabel" for="Country">Country<span class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
        <g:select name="Country" id="Country" from="${dbinfo...Country.list().sort{it.orderNumber}}" class="form-control" required="" optionKey="id" value="${Instance.Country}" aria-labelledby="Country-label"/>              
    </div>    

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label id="State-label" class="toplabel" for=State>State<span id="StateAsterisk" class="required-indicator">*</span></label>
    <g:select name="State" id="State" from="${[]}" class="form-control" optionKey="id" value="${...Instance.State}" noSelection="['null':'']" aria-labelledby="State-label"/>
</div>
```

Rendered HTML from Firebug:

```
<select id="Country" class="form-control" aria-labelledby="Country-label" required="" name="Country">
<option selected="selected" value="100225">United States</option>

<select aria-labelledby="State-label" class="form-control" id="State" name="State">
<option value="null"></option>
<option value="102722">Alabama</option>
<option value="102723">Alaska</option>
```

Geb selector excerpt from test:

```
       println $('#Country').value()

        waitFor(5){$('#Country').click()}
        $('#Country').value(100225)  // USA
        waitFor(10){$('#Country').find("option").find{ it.value() == 100225 }.click()}   // USA

        println $('#State').value()  // --> RETURNS NULL VALUE

        $('#State').find("option").find{ it.value() == 102722}.click() // --> NONE OF THESE WILL HIT

        waitFor(5){$('#State').click()}  // --> NONE OF THESE WILL HIT
        waitFor(5){$('#State').value(102722)}   // --> NONE OF THESE WILL HIT
```

Javascript/Ajax call - that loads states based on country USA:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Country').change(function() {
            var country = $(this).val();
            if(country != null && country != 'null'){
                loadStates(country, null, 'submitter', true);
            }
        });
        <g:if test="${...Country}">
            $('#Country').val(${...Country}); 
            loadStates(${...Country}, "${...State?:null}", 'submitter', true);
        </g:if>

    var xhr = null;
    function loadStates(country, state, selectId, hideShowAsterisk){
        if(xhr != null){
            xhr.abort();
            xhr = null;
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
                    url: '${request.contextPath}.../aj/loadStatesByCountry',
                    data: { country: country, selectId:selectId },
                    async:false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#'+selectId+'State').html(data);
                        $('#'+selectId+'State-label').show();
                        if(state){
                            $('#'+selectId+'State').val(state);
                        }
                        if(hideShowAsterisk){
                            if(country == ${grailsApplication....country.usa}){
                                $('#'+selectId+'StateAsterisk').show();
                            }else{
                                $('#'+selectId+'StateAsterisk').hide();
                            }
                        }
                        xhr = null;
                    },
                    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                        if(textStatus != 'abort'){
                            xhr = null;
                            alert("There was an error requesting the States for the selected Country");
                        }
                    }
       });
    }
```

Comment: Trigger the change event after setting the value. Or use the widgets value method which should trigger a change event. $('#Change').change()

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

```
waitFor(30){$("form").State = "102722"}
```

Comment: no I tried waitFor(5) and waitFor(10) - but I was told to never use a waitFor for anything over 10 seconds.   Is it ok to do waitFor(30)?   For some reason - I can't get that selector to trigger the Ajax function.  Maybe a longer wait is the key?

Comment: I see no harm in trying that to isolate the cause however not suggesting to use it as practice.